# PhantomJS not rendering extra information after object class changed

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to get tabulated information that only shows once a side menu item is clicked. The side menu item is a list item whose class changes when the information I need is displayed. The list item is:

```
<li class="treeItem" dataid="1" parentid="0" sportid="HOR"><div class="treeItemText">Horse Racing<div>
```

When the user clicks on "Horse Racing" in the left hand panel that contains this list item, the class "open" is added to that list item, and then the list item expands revealing codes necessary to generate the table

```
<li class="treeItem open" dataid="1" parentid="0" sportid="HOR" loaded="true"><div class="treeItemText">Horse Racing<div></div></div><div class="loader" style="display: none; "></div><ul class="level1" style="display: block; "><li class="treeItem" dataid="65365" parentid="1" sportid="HOR"><div class="treeItemText">Dundalk<div></div></div><div class="loader"></div><div class="checkbox">&nbsp;</div></li><li class="treeItem" dataid="79261" parentid="1" sportid="HOR"><div class="treeItemText">Exeter<div></div></div><div class="loader"></div><div class="checkbox">&nbsp;</div></li><li class="treeItem" dataid="71557" parentid="1" sportid="HOR"><div class="treeItemText">Fairview<div></div></div><div class="loader"></div><div class="checkbox">&nbsp;</div></li><li class="treeItem" dataid="65428" parentid="1" sportid="HOR"><div class="treeItemText">Happy Valley<div></div></div><div class="loader"></div><div class="checkbox">&nbsp;</div></li><li class="treeItem" dataid="65433" parentid="1" sportid="HOR"><div class="treeItemText">Kempton<div></div></div><div class="loader"></div><div class="checkbox">&nbsp;</div></li><li class="treeItem" dataid="71544" parentid="1" sportid="HOR"><div class="treeItemText">Kenilworth<div></div></div><div class="loader"></div><div class="checkbox">&nbsp;</div></li><li class="treeItem" dataid="68710" parentid="1" sportid="HOR"><div class="treeItemText">Lingfield<div></div></div><div class="loader"></div><div class="checkbox">&nbsp;</div></li><li class="treeItem" dataid="69378" parentid="1" sportid="HOR"><div class="treeItemText">Summer Cup - Antepost<div></div></div><div class="loader"></div><div class="checkbox">&nbsp;</div></li><li class="treeItem" dataid="65459" parentid="1" sportid="HOR"><div class="treeItemText">Turffontein Standside<div></div></div><div class="loader"></div><div class="checkbox">&nbsp;</div></li><li class="treeItem" dataid="65463" parentid="1" sportid="HOR"><div class="treeItemText">Vaal Sand<div></div></div><div class="loader"></div><div class="checkbox">&nbsp;</div></li></ul></li>
```

I have successfully (9 hours, I had trouble with addClass after finding the element based on attribute) managed to add "open" to the list items class using the following javascript

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.bettingworld.co.za/', function (s) {

window.setTimeout(function () { 
    var sports = page.evaluate(function(){
        $( "li:eq(48)" ).addClass( "open" );

        console.log("YYYYYY");
     });

    page.render('page.png');
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
}, 60000);

});
```

and running phantomjs at the command line `jason:>./phantomjs javaRender.js > new.html` (My internet connection was thru my mobile, so I set the timeout to be a minute.).
Though the class has changed, the list item is not opening, and I can't see the needed data in the output (new.html). I am not well experienced with JavaScript, but assume that clicking the item in the menu causes some javascript on the page to execute.
I went through the javascripts on the page, but there are quite a few, and the variable names are single characters (arg!).
I am hoping though the reason why the extra data is not being rendered is because I am doing something obviously wrong as far as rendering the page. Would that be the case, or do I need to find the javascript that is executed when I click on the list item? I can't see a call to a javascript "*on clicked*" which is what I would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that onClick, the "open" class is added to that li element.  But that's not the only thing!  In addition, an asynchronous network request (AJAX) is made which requests the html/data for the submenu; they show a small spinner gif while it loads.

So to simulate this behavior in PhantomJS, you'll have to actually recreate that click.  Which is not too far from what you have!  To start with, instead of adding the `open` class to that `<li/>` element, you would do this:

```
 $( "li:eq(48)" ).click();
```

This will kick off the AJAX request to fetch the submenu contents.  From there, you'll need "wait" for the submenu elements to load.  There's a PhantomJS utility called [waitfor.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) which does exactly this: you tell it to wait until some condition is satisfied (in this case, submenu is loaded) and then you can finish your function.

So in your example, it might look something like this:

```
function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 3000, //< Default Max Timout is 3s
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if(!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
};

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.bettingworld.co.za/', function (s) {

    window.setTimeout(function () { 
        var sports = page.evaluate(function(){
            $( "li:eq(48)" ).click()
         });
        waitFor(function() {
            // Check in the page if a specific element is now visible
            return page.evaluate(function() {
                return ($( "li:eq(48)" ).find('.level1').length > 0);
            });
        }, function() {
            // once it's visible, you can exit & spit out any html
            page.render('page.png');
            console.log(page.content);
           console.log("submenu open");
           phantom.exit();
        });    
    }, 60000);

});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This was just the extra I needed. It works like a dream.